# Autocomplete/sql to fill input field 2 after onblur on input1

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Okay, here it goes. Basically I have two input fiels. First one works like charm, I autocomplete from a huge database a name, that onblur after selecting it, should automatically fill input field 2 via a php script, that searches for the selected string in my database and populates the input field with as many hits as it gets. How can I do that?

So: If the first input's autocomplete finds the string, as it's already stored (with multiple id's on the same name), it should get those id's. If there is no string found in db on first input, i already have an autocomplete written for multi selecting the id's manually on the second box, then submitting them. But that is not important now. So again, how can I populate the second input with the given string found in the database from the first input? So far I have this as barebone:

```
<input type="text" size="20" onBlur"" id="firstinput" name="firstinput">
<input type="text" size="40" value="" id="manualorautogroup" name="manualorautogroup">
```

php that json_encodes the results:

```
$lolz = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {

$lolz[] = array(
'value' => $row['gameid'],
echo json_encode($lolz);
);
}
```

How is my client side code call this and gets the data to be filled into input 2?

database sample:

gameid                         groupname

122                       stringtypedininput1foundyautocomplete

314                       stringtypedininput1foundyautocomplete

513                      stringtypedininput1foundyautocomplete

533                      stringtypedininput1foundyautocomplete

Many thanks :)

Comment: the echo needs to be outside of the while loop. the way you have it now won't work. When you receive the data from the ajax call, you'll need to to use `success: function(data){` and then inside you'll need to set the `source of the autocomplete` for the 2nd input to the array you send back from the server.

Comment: the echo is inside the array. That can be a problem.

Comment: Normally the echo is outside the while call yes, my mistake pasting it to the wrong position. but still, because I'm very muh of a beginner in JS, would someone be kind enough to drop in a few client side lines, so I can understand what the first commenter wanted me to do?

Comment: Ohgodwhy please, or anyone? :)